# Modal Dialogs with Iframe zIndex

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

[image]

On my page I have a div which contains an iframe. On this div there is a button which also calls a second modal. When calling this second modal it appears below the iframe on the first modal. How can I set the z-index of this second modal so it appears above the iframe.

I'm using jquery 1.9.

I've tried some CSS on z-Index but no luck. Looks like its an IE issue only.

```
<style type="text/css">
#diag2 { z-Index: 1000  !important }
</style>

<script type="javascript>
    $(function() {
        $('#diag1').dialog({ modal: true, width: 800, height: 600 });

        $('#btncalldiag2').click(function() { 
            $('#diag2').dialog({ modal: true, width: 800, height: 600 });
        });
    }); 
</script>


<div id="diag1">
    <iframe src="..."></iframe>
    <button id="btncalldiag2">Do something</button>
</div>
<div id="diag2">
    <div>information</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I've added an image. The iframe as you can see sits on the Assign modal. The 2nd modal Search appears but it sits behind the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

for a element to have `z-index` it also needs `position:absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`.

Comment: "Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)." - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp CHECK your sources before you downvote something!

Comment: @Slugge w3schools is [not regarded very highly](http://www.w3fools.com/) as a reference

Comment: Does not make it any less true. I could cite other sources, but this is very basic knowledge of how z-index works. "z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static" - http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/ better?

Comment: sorry, obviously being grumpy and not thinking, it was late!